# what is the meaning of "measure the universe" at this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of "measure the universe" at this paragraph?

> A wise man recognizes that God may be approached from
>   innumerable angles. The minds of men and the spirit of the times vary
>   in their reaction to the great central cause, and one can only insist upon
>   a broad charity both in oneself and in others. It was in this that Irving
>   seems to have been wanting. It was always by the standard of that
>   which was a sect among sects that he would **measure the universe**.
>   There were times when he was vaguely conscious of this, and it may be
>   that those wrestlings with Apollyon, of which he complains, even as
>   Bunyan and the Puritans of old used to comes plain, had a strange
>   explanation. Apollyon was really the Spirit of Truth, and the inward
>   struggle was not between Faith and Sin, but was really between the
>   darkness of inherited dogma, and the light of inherent and instinctive
>   reason, God-given, and rising for ever in revolt against the absurdities
>   of man.

Comment: You should understand ***sect*** here as referring to "a group of people with non-standard / extreme / dangerous views". The (probably, "one-off") coinage ***a sect among sects*** effectively *exaggerates* that "deviation from mainstream thought" sense (even by the standards of "sects" in general, this one is particularly "unconventional"). Essentially, it's saying that Irving was *exceptionally* unusual because of his "extreme commitment" (to the idea of being "charitable" to everyone, regardless of how unusual their opinions might seem, as I understand it from a brief scan).

Answer (score 1):

The quotation is from *History of Spiritualism* by Arthur Conan Doyle, vol 1, page 28, where he is writing about Edward Irving.  (Text at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/historyofspiritu015638mbp/historyofspiritu015638mbp_djvu.txt))

A few sentences before your quotation, Doyle says:

> Here, in Gray's Inn
>   Road, Irving  rallied the faithful. It cannot be denied that the 
>   Church, as he organized it, with its angel, its elders,  its deacons,
>   its tongues, and its prophecies, was the  best reconstruction of a
>   primitive Christian Church  that has ever been made.

Now regarding your quotation "**It was always by the standard of that which was a sect among sects that he would measure the universe**":

The sect which is referred to is the group at Irving's church, it is a "sect amongst sects" because it is a narrow branch of a narrow branch of Christianity.  Irving applied the standards of this group to everything.